# How to evaluate $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-ax^2}}{xe^{x^4}}dx$ , $a >- 1$

Tags: integration

How i can evaluate

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1-e^{-ax^2}}{xe^{x^4}}dx $$  $ a > -1$

Tried to use differentiation, but got

$$f' = xe^{-ax^2-x^4}$$

This seems impossible to integrate, so i don't know.

Comment: Try substituting $u=x^2$.

Comment: There is a quite nasty solution for $a>0$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you consider $$I= \int x\,e^{-ax^2-x^4}\,dx$$ first, as Mark Viola commented, use $x^2=y$ making $$I=\frac 12 \int e^{-ay-y^2}\,dy$$  Now, complete the square
$$y^2+ay=\left(y+\frac a 2\right)^2-\frac {a^2} 4$$ making 
$$I=\frac 12 e^{\frac {a^2} 4}\int e^{-\left(y+\frac a 2\right)^2 }\,dy$$ Now $y=t-\frac a2$ makes $$I=\frac 12 e^{\frac {a^2} 4}\int e^{-t^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}  e^{\frac{a^2}{4}} \text{erf}(t)$$ If you want to go back to $x$, this would give $$I=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}  e^{\frac{a^2}{4}} \text{erf}\left(x^2+\frac a2\right)$$ and $$J=\int_0^\infty x\,e^{-ax^2-x^4}\,dx=\frac{\sqrt{\pi }}{4}  e^{\frac{a^2}{4}} \text{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

$F'(a) = 0.5\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax^2-x^{4}}dx^2 = 0.5 \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-at-t^{2}}$.

Now $at+ t^{2} = u$, so $du = \sqrt{a^{2}+4u} dt$, then $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-u}}{\sqrt{a^2+4u}}$. The last one is easy to calculate by changing denominator $\sqrt{a^2+4u} = m$.

Comment: I can miss some constant, but it's not a problem to find them!

Answer (score 0):

Treating $a$ as a parameter, then

$$
I(a)=\int_0^{\infty} \frac{1-e^{-a x^2}}{x e^{x^4}} d x
$$
Differentiating $I(a)$ w.r.t. $a$ yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(a) & =\int_0^{\infty} \frac{x^2 e^{-a x^2}}{x e^{x^4}} d x \\
& =\int_0^{\infty} x e^{-x^4-a x^2} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-x^2-a x} d x \text { via } x^2 \rightarrow x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{a^2}{4}} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{a^2}{4}} \int_0^{\infty} e^{-\left(x+\frac{a}{2}\right)^2} d x \\
& =\frac{1}{2} e^{\frac{a^2}{4}} \cdot \frac{1}{2} \sqrt{\pi} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right) \\
& =\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} e^{\frac{a^2}{2}} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
However, when we go back to $I(a)$ by integrating
$$
I(a)=I(a)-I(0)=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{4} \int_0^a e^{\frac{x^2}{2}} \operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right) d x,
$$
we are stuck here.